# Multiple actions on product page (Add to basket, to wish list, as a stock item)

Tags: interaction-design, android

I'm working on an App that sells construction tools but also allows users to manage a stock they might have of the companies products.

On the product page the user can take three main actions:

- Add to Basket
- Add to Favourites
- Add as a Stock item

I need to have a fixed/overlay bar in the same style as Ebay does.

**Ebay and Amazon examples**

[image] [image]

Which of the images below is the best solution? open to new suggestions.

Also, is the icon on the right the right choice? I used a similar thing to the Android action overflow (From the Android website: "Action overflow: Move less often used actions to the action overflow.") but not sure if it would cause confusion to use a native interaction icon in a specific page context.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNlf6R.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to sell products to customers, it should be made apparently clear how to “Add product to Basket” and “Check-Out” the product and pay. For this reason alone, option two is the preferred one. It is clear, and to the point. One click less is one click less of a bailout.

The dots are commonly known as “More…” option where favorites and stock items should be.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't put all three buttons (why not?), another option is an action combo button where the primary (or most important for your site) action is the default. When the user clicks in the "button" area the displayed action is triggered. The other actions are available by clicking the down arrow.

[image: Action combo button]

Comment: why would this be better than any of the other options?

Comment: As it would have to be a fixed bar at the bottom of the screen, 3 buttons would take too much screen space on a mobile. I do like your solution but I'd still need a second button to apply the action

Comment: You don't necessarily need a second button to apply the action. Since the first part of the element is a button, the user can click on 'Add to Cart' to execute the action. The other two actions are triggered automatically when the user selects the option from the drop-down.